# What is a good duration between two garbage collections on production JVMs?

Tags: garbage-collection, jvm

I am trying to figure out what would be a good duration between two garbage collections on JVM 8 in production.

I can tune the memory available on the JVM and as a side effect it will increase the duration between two garbage collections but how do I distinguish between a normal situation or one where we do not have enough memory allocated for the machine.

This problem applies especially to systems like Jira and Confluence, you can have a look at the screenshot. Currently a garbage collection take places about every 3 hours.

[image]

> /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.
>   ClassLoaderLogManager -Xms15000m -Xmx15000m -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow ... org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start

Comment: Not enough information, this is a "it depends" thing. What are your goals? Footprint, pause times or throughput? Have you actually experienced any problems you're now trying to avoid?

Comment: Yes, for the first time I got a an outage due to the "GC overhead limit exceeded". In the past I got the normal out of memory exception and the solution was simple, to increase the memory, but now I've seen this one. I will provide more information, in a minute.

Comment: so you basically want to know where the line is between normal GC activity and the GC running too often due to a leak or insufficient heap space?

Comment: @the8462 Indeed, that's what I want to know: how to distinguish from something that would be normal / acceptable performance, or something that needs further tuning like increasing the memory or altering other parameters.

Answer (score 0):

GCs running in itself is not really a good indicator of anything. Minor GCs can run several times per second on some workloads without that signifying anything bad. And even concurrent (CMS)/mixed (G1) GC phases running once a minute or so can be normal on some workloads.

Two better measures are the following:

- *how much heap is freed by a old gen GC.* If the utilization barely goes down at all that either is an extremely carefully tuned application or you're approaching an OOME either due to insufficient heap space or a memory leak in the application.
- *how many CPU cycles are spent in GC vs. CPU cycles in application time* - it sort of follows from the first point. If the GC can collect very little garbage it will have to run again very soon as garbage keeps piling up.
  This is what triggers the `GC overhead limit exceeded` OOME in the first place, the JVM keeps track of how much time it spends in GCing and throws that exception when it exceeds the default limit.

There are exceptions to point two, for example single-threaded applications that use a concurrent collector to burn CPU cycles for GCing on another core to achieve higher throughput.

For a web application you can't really judge things based on GC intervals because those will vary with user demand and with in-memory caches/data stores/databases being warmed up as users start utilizing the system each day. It also depends on how those caches get freed/scrubbed of stale entries.

You basically have to read the documentation of your application which kind of in-memory stores it uses and how they can be tuned / limited.

Running a realistic load test that emulates multiple users and crawls many pages of your application might also give you a good baseline how much memory it'll need.